# How to prove this equation of probability?

Tags: probability

The question is as follows.

> Of three independent events, the chance that only the first occurs is $a$, the chance that only the second occurs is $b$, and the chance that only the third occurs is $c$. Show that the chances of the three events are $a/(a+x)$, $b/(b+x)$ and $c/(c+x)$ respectively, where $x$ is a root of the equation $(a+x)(b+x)(c+x)=x^2$.

How to formulate the required proof? So far, I know that:
$$ a=p(1-q)(1-r) \\ b=(1-p)q(1-r) \\ c=(1-p)(1-q)r $$
where $p$, $q$ and $r$ are the probabilities of the first, second and the third events respectively. If we substitute $p=a/(a+x)$, $q=b/(b+x)$ and $r=c/(c+x)$, then all the three equations can be rearranged to give the cubic equation in $x$ that is given in the question. But I am not sure how that can be made into a proof. Multiplying all three equations doesn't seem to help.

So, **how can the required statement be proved**? Also, **is it possible to arrive at the statement that is to be proved, with only the knowledge of $a$, $b$ and $c$**?

Thank you!

Comment: I think what you have done is a valid proof.

Comment: @Peter Well, is it possible to, like, derive the solution or something? Could we have found out the equations involving $x$ just from the knowledge of $a,b$ and $c$? Also, is this the way to find the actual values of $p,q$ and $r$, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What does $x$ represent?

You have that  $p= \dfrac{a}{(1-q)(1-r)}$ and want that $p=\dfrac{a}{a+x}$

So you want: $(1-q)(1-r)=a+x$

Or to look at it another way:

> $$\mathsf P(B^\complement\cap C^\complement) = {\mathsf P(A \cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement)+x}$$

Comment: Okay! That helps a lot! So I found that $x=(1-p)(1-q)(1-r)$ from your hint. So should the proof be like, "Suppose $x=(1-p)(1-q)(1-r)$", and then show that "with this definition, we can get $p=a/(a+x)$" and so on? Is this the correct way?